# How to deactivate backup apps on other phone remotely?

Tags: gmail, google-account, cloud, onedrive

I dont have the phone. Its my old phone but I am still logged onto my mail. How can I deactivate it from my actual phone? I dont have the old phone on me.

Comment: What kind of phone was it? What kind of phone do you have now? When you say that you don't have access to your old phone, is this a permanent situation - you traded it in or sold it - or you just don't have it with you at the moment? What version of the OS is running on your old/new phones?

Comment: What backup? Google drive, or Samsung or what?

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming that you want to stop your Google account from syncing to your phone.*

To stop Google from syncing to your device, you should sign out of your account. To do that remotely, go to [this](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity) page, sign into the same account as the one on your old phone, scroll down to the bottom of the page, press on the name of the device, and press *remove*. This will remove your account from your old phone and will stop any new info from coming in. You'll have to sign back in, in order to resume sync.

If you want to fully erase everything that's on the phone, go to [Android.com/find](http://Android.com/find) log into your account, and press *erase* in the pop-up press *erase* again. As long as your phone is *on* and has internet connection, everything that's on it will be deleted.